# Navigating Many to Many Relationships Django

Tags: python, django

I need get the list of Items name and qty for a given menu. how can i query and return a QuerySet with the needed columns.?

i only get the list of menus but still cannot get qty. should i do multiple queries or try using raw sql

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Meals(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='MealRecipe')


 class Menu(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     meals = models.ManyToManyField(Meals,through='CompMenu')


 class CompMenu(models.Model):
     TYPE_COMP = (
         ('B', 'Breakfast'),
         ('L', 'Lunch'),
         ('D', 'Dinner')
     )
     menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu)
     meal = models.ForeignKey(Meals)
     type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_COMP)

class MealRecipe(models.Model):
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correclty, you can get `name` and `qty` by this way:

```
menu = Menu.objects.filter(name='some_name')
meals_of_menu = menu[idx].meals.all()

receipes = MealRecipe.objects.filter(meal__in=meals_of_menu)
for receipe in receipes:
    name = receipe.item.name
    qty = receipe.qty
```

Comment: thanks, how can i get the list of items for a given list of meals that are related to a given menu. should i use multiple queries?

Comment: i get object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: I hope now I understood your problem correctly and made appropriate changes.

Comment: It worked, but first i changed the line meals_of_menu = menu[idx].meals.all()

Comment: @gaccep Changed as you suggested. Glad to help. Could you accept the answer please (in front of my answer there is a grey check mark under up\down arrows). Thank you.

Comment: Hi @TitanFighter, do you know how could i serialize a list of items with name and id and the corresponding quantities for a given menu? Thanks in advance

Comment: @gaccep, probably yes. What format do you want to have? Could be `meal_ingredients = [(id_ingredient_1, name_ingrediend_1, quantity_ingrediend_1), (id_ingredient_2, name_ingrediend_2, quantity_ingrediend_2), (...), (id_ingredient_5, name_ingrediend_5, quantity_ingrediend_5)]` or I think a dict of items could be better, something like `meal_ingredients = {id_ingredient_1: (name_ingrediend_1, quantity_ingrediend_1), id_ingredient_2: (name_ingrediend_2, quantity_ingrediend_2), ..., id_ingredient_5: (name_ingrediend_5, quantity_ingrediend_5)}`

Answer (score 0):

`MealRecipe.objects.filter(meal__menu=some_menu_instance).distinct()` should do it, if I recall correctly. Or `meal__menu__id=some_id` if you have the menu ID rather than an instance, etc. It's just a standard cross-relation query.